# Consul-Template Unexpected response code: 504

Tags: consul, consul-template, consul-kv

I am using Consul-Template to render a properties with the data gathered from Consul. The files are being rendered successfully but afterwards Consul-Template fails over and over again until it crashes:

```
2017/08/16 10:43:04.900637 [WARN] (view) kv.list(...): Unexpected response code: 504 (retry attempt 5 after "4s")
```

This goes on and on with longer pauses until limit is reached / it crashes.

Configuration pulled from the logs:

```
2017/08/16 10:38:02.403969 [DEBUG] (runner) final config:
{
    "Consul": {
        "Address": "consul-client.development.discovery",
        "Auth": {
            "Enabled": false,
            "Username": "",
            "Password": ""
        },
        "Retry": {
            "Attempts": 12,
            "Backoff": 250000000,
            "MaxBackoff": 60000000000,
            "Enabled": true
        },
        "SSL": {
            "CaCert": "",
            "CaPath": "",
            "Cert": "",
            "Enabled": false,
            "Key": "",
            "ServerName": "",
            "Verify": true
        },
        "Token": "",
        "Transport": {
            "DialKeepAlive": 30000000000,
            "DialTimeout": 30000000000,
            "DisableKeepAlives": false,
            "IdleConnTimeout": 90000000000,
            "MaxIdleConns": 100,
            "MaxIdleConnsPerHost": 3,
            "TLSHandshakeTimeout": 10000000000
        }
    },
    "Dedup": {
        "Enabled": false,
        "MaxStale": 2000000000,
        "Prefix": "consul-template/dedup/",
        "TTL": 15000000000
    },
    "Exec": {
        "Command": "",
        "Enabled": false,
        "Env": {
            "Blacklist": [],
            "Custom": [],
            "Pristine": false,
            "Whitelist": []
        },
        "KillSignal": 2,
        "KillTimeout": 30000000000,
        "ReloadSignal": null,
        "Splay": 0,
        "Timeout": 0
    },
    "KillSignal": 2,
    "LogLevel": "DEBUG",
    "MaxStale": 2000000000,
    "PidFile": "",
    "ReloadSignal": 1,
    "Syslog": {
        "Enabled": false,
        "Facility": "LOCAL0"
    },
    "Templates": [
        {
            "Backup": false,
            "Command": "",
            "CommandTimeout": 30000000000,
            "Contents": "",
            "Destination": "/consul-template/output/service.properties",
            "Exec": {
                "Command": "",
                "Enabled": false,
                "Env": {
                    "Blacklist": [],
                    "Custom": [],
                    "Pristine": false,
                    "Whitelist": []
                },
                "KillSignal": 2,
                "KillTimeout": 30000000000,
                "ReloadSignal": null,
                "Splay": 0,
                "Timeout": 30000000000
            },
            "Perms": 420,
            "Source": "/consul-template/data/service.properties.tpl",
            "Wait": {
                "Enabled": false,
                "Min": 0,
                "Max": 0
            },
            "LeftDelim": "",
            "RightDelim": ""
        },
        {
            "Backup": false,
            "Command": "",
            "CommandTimeout": 30000000000,
            "Contents": "",
            "Destination": "/consul-template/output/application.properties",
            "Exec": {
                "Command": "",
                "Enabled": false,
                "Env": {
                    "Blacklist": [],
                    "Custom": [],
                    "Pristine": false,
                    "Whitelist": []
                },
                "KillSignal": 2,
                "KillTimeout": 30000000000,
                "ReloadSignal": null,
                "Splay": 0,
                "Timeout": 30000000000
            },
            "Perms": 420,
            "Source": "/consul-template/data/application.properties.tpl",
            "Wait": {
                "Enabled": false,
                "Min": 0,
                "Max": 0
            },
            "LeftDelim": "",
            "RightDelim": ""
        },
        {
            "Backup": false,
            "Command": "",
            "CommandTimeout": 30000000000,
            "Contents": "",
            "Destination": "/consul-template/output/anotherMicroConsul.properties",
            "Exec": {
                "Command": "",
                "Enabled": false,
                "Env": {
                    "Blacklist": [],
                    "Custom": [],
                    "Pristine": false,
                    "Whitelist": []
                },
                "KillSignal": 2,
                "KillTimeout": 30000000000,
                "ReloadSignal": null,
                "Splay": 0,
                "Timeout": 30000000000
            },
            "Perms": 420,
            "Source": "/consul-template/data/anotherMicroConsul.properties.tpl",
            "Wait": {
                "Enabled": false,
                "Min": 0,
                "Max": 0
            },
            "LeftDelim": "",
            "RightDelim": ""
        },
        {
            "Backup": false,
            "Command": "",
            "CommandTimeout": 30000000000,
            "Contents": "",
            "Destination": "/consul-template/output/master.properties",
            "Exec": {
                "Command": "",
                "Enabled": false,
                "Env": {
                    "Blacklist": [],
                    "Custom": [],
                    "Pristine": false,
                    "Whitelist": []
                },
                "KillSignal": 2,
                "KillTimeout": 30000000000,
                "ReloadSignal": null,
                "Splay": 0,
                "Timeout": 30000000000
            },
            "Perms": 420,
            "Source": "/consul-template/data/master.properties.tpl",
            "Wait": {
                "Enabled": false,
                "Min": 0,
                "Max": 0
            },
            "LeftDelim": "",
            "RightDelim": ""
        },
        {
            "Backup": false,
            "Command": "",
            "CommandTimeout": 30000000000,
            "Contents": "",
            "Destination": "/consul-template/output/microConsul.properties",
            "Exec": {
                "Command": "",
                "Enabled": false,
                "Env": {
                    "Blacklist": [],
                    "Custom": [],
                    "Pristine": false,
                    "Whitelist": []
                },
                "KillSignal": 2,
                "KillTimeout": 30000000000,
                "ReloadSignal": null,
                "Splay": 0,
                "Timeout": 30000000000
            },
            "Perms": 420,
            "Source": "/consul-template/data/microConsul.properties.tpl",
            "Wait": {
                "Enabled": false,
                "Min": 0,
                "Max": 0
            },
            "LeftDelim": "",
            "RightDelim": ""
        }
    ],
    "Vault": {
        "Address": "",
        "Enabled": false,
        "Grace": 15000000000,
        "RenewToken": true,
        "Retry": {
            "Attempts": 12,
            "Backoff": 250000000,
            "MaxBackoff": 60000000000,
            "Enabled": true
        },
        "SSL": {
            "CaCert": "",
            "CaPath": "",
            "Cert": "",
            "Enabled": true,
            "Key": "",
            "ServerName": "",
            "Verify": true
        },
        "Transport": {
            "DialKeepAlive": 30000000000,
            "DialTimeout": 30000000000,
            "DisableKeepAlives": false,
            "IdleConnTimeout": 90000000000,
            "MaxIdleConns": 100,
            "MaxIdleConnsPerHost": 3,
            "TLSHandshakeTimeout": 10000000000
        },
        "UnwrapToken": false
    },
    "Wait": {
        "Enabled": false,
        "Min": 0,
        "Max": 0
    }
}
```

Sifting through the code this error message seems to be coming from `Renew` in [session.go](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template/blob/a519d8ab481d4662e56036782e0854a10d8029f6/vendor/github.com/hashicorp/consul/api/session.go#L132).

Am I supposed to see a session in Consul under `/session/list`? I have multiple Consul-Template containers running (one on each host) - Am I supposed to see several sessions? Right now I don't see anything...

```
curl localhost:8500/v1/session/list
[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cause**: You have a proxy or a load balancer between your consul-template and consul.

**Workaround**: Increase your load balancer or proxy timeout for idle connections to something above 60sec (e.g: 65sec or 120sec) because after that keepalive will kick in and will keep the connection alive :)

**Details**

- HTTP 504 is a gateway timeout that means the connection has been "cut" or that the service became unresponsive but I will assume that your consul cluster is still working therefore it is due to an active network device in middle (between consul-template and consul)
- Consul-template opens long lasting connections to listen for changes. Therefore if the connection is silently killed by a load balancer you end up with these 504 errors.
- These messages are benign because consul-template reconnects fine. However they are annoying and will fill your logs and disk space with the same warning over and over ;-)
- If in AWS, set your ELB idle timeout to 65sec and these messages will go away

Comment: in AWS ALB we set to 300 seconds and waittime to 3 mins but still getting 504 timeout